# Detecting 'Return' key pressed from an external keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there a way to detect when the "Return" key is pressed from an external keyboard connected to an iOS device as opposed to a tap on the onscreen keyboard's "Return" key?

Is this possible with public APIs?

My class is serving as `UITextFieldDelegate` and I get the call from:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

But when it's called, `textField.text` returns the characters present in the text field but not the carriage return that was issued.

`-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` isn't invoked with the "Return" key press for both physical or virtual keyboards.

Comment: You have the same behavior for both types of keyboards. An carriage return can't be entered in to a `UITextField`. When the return key is tapped, the `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method should be called and the text field should not have the carriage return character added. Are you seeing different behavior between the two types of keyboards?

Comment: With both keyboard types, I'm not seeing the carriage return in the UITextField. So that behavior is correct. Turns out it's a bug in a 3rd party library I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7+, you can use [`UIKeyCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand) to distinguish Return via hardware keyboard.

```swift
extension ViewController {
    
    @objc private func keyCommand_return() {
        /// handle return
    }
    
    
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyCommand_return)),
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A subclass of `UITextField` should work:

```
protocol TextFieldKeyDetectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func enterKeyWasPressed(textField: UITextField)
    func shiftEnterKeyPressed(textField: UITextField)
}

class TextFieldWithKeyDetection: UITextField {
    weak var keyDelegate: TextFieldKeyDetectionDelegate?
    
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        [UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: .shift, action: #selector(shiftEnterKeyPressed)),
         UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(enterKeyPressed))]
    }
    
    @objc func shiftEnterKeyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        keyDelegate?.shiftEnterKeyPressed(textField: self)
    }
    
    @objc func enterKeyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        keyDelegate?.enterKeyWasPressed(textField: self)
    }
}
```